# Linear momentum density of light in general case

Tags: optics, visible-light, classical-electrodynamics, tensor-calculus, structural-beam

If I am given a photon wave function of the form:

$\vec{A} = \hat{x} \;u(r,\phi,z)\; e^{-ikz}$

where $u(r,\phi,z)$ is a distribution of the field amplitude (linear polarization).

Then the linear momentum density can be written as

$p = \frac{\epsilon_2}{2}(\vec{E}^* \cdot \vec{B}+\vec{E} \cdot \vec{B}^*) = i\frac{\epsilon_0 \omega}{2}(u^*\nabla u-u\nabla u^*)+ \omega k \epsilon_0 |u|^2\hat{z}$

No matter how long I stare at this, I can't see it. How can I prove the last equality sign?

[This](https://journals.aps.org/pra/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevA.45.8185) is the link to the source article.

My feeling is that essentially it boils down to expressing linear momentum density in terms of vector potential in general case.

Comment: I haven't really worked it out but the last equality seems to come from setting E = -delA/delt = -i omega A and B = curl A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation is not fully correct or at least I cannot reproduce it without further approximation.
If you use
\begin{align}
E& = i\omega A = i\omega  u e^{-ikz} \vec{x} \\
B& = \nabla \times A = \partial_z u e^{-ikz} \vec{y} - \partial_y u e^{-ikz}\vec{z}
\end{align}

The $E^*\times B$ term in the momentum is given by
\begin{align}
E^*\times B = i\omega\;  u^* (\partial_y\vec{y}+\partial_z\vec{z})u+\omega k |u|^2\vec{z}
\end{align}
If you insert that into the equation for $p$ you will find the result from the paper except, that the x component of the gradient in $u\nabla u^*$ is missing. The momentum must have a vanishing x-component because E is parallel to A and A points only in the x direction.

Comment: Yeah, I got that one, except in my case $\partial_z$ is missing. He states that he dropped it, I just don't get why he dropped it in grad, but didn't drop it deriving the last term... Anyways, now I have troubles with eqn. (9). Allen doesn't explain the difference between $\phi$ and $\Phi$... I don't get how he obtained this last term there.

Comment: The idea is typically that $u$ varies very little in propagation (here z) direction and more in transverse direction, i.e. it determines the beam profile. The somewhat puzzeling part is that $\partial_x \vec{x} u$ is added, which is certainly not small. $\phi$ is a coordinate of the polar coordinate system and $\Phi$  is the respective unit vector $(-\sin\phi,\cos\phi,0)$